# Does Apache PDFBox or Apache FOP provide functinality like Birt Report runtime to generate dynamic PDFs by providing custom templates?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, apache-fop

Currently I am using Birt Report runtime version which takes .rptdesign files as a template and data from database to create/render dynamic pdfs. It also renders pdf on web browser.

I am looking similar functionality in Apache PDFBox  where I can provide custom templates and generated pdfs dynamically by providing data through database.

I have checked Apache FOP and it uses only XSLT as template to generate pdf files